# How can I speed up my animations to make my EarlGrey test suite run faster

Tags: xctest, earlgrey

I saw the below API in `GREYConfiguration` that says that EarlGrey by default truncates CALayer animations more than 10 seconds -

```
/**
 *  Configuration for setting max allowable animation duration (in seconds) for any CALayer based
 *  animation. Animations exceeding the specified time will have their duration truncated to value
 *  specified by this config.
 *
 *  Accepted values: @c double (negative values shouldn't be used)
 *  Default value: 10.0
 */
GREY_EXTERN NSString *const kGREYConfigKeyCALayerMaxAnimationDuration;
```

I'm developing a small gaming app that has a number of such animations going on. I noticed that my tests take a long time to run when I have my animations enabled, which is required for my UI Tests. I know that I can change the animation speed for my entire app using `UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.layer.speed`. Is there any way that I can change it only for my EarlGrey tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your `UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.layer.speed` behind a conditional statement:

```
#if EARLGREY_ENV
UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.layer.speed = 100
#endif
```

The line of code will only execute when the app is being run through Earl Grey.

For more information around dealing with animations in Earl Grey, see *How should I handle animations?* under [their FAQs](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/faq.md).